What is this device in my ceiling making out of battery chirps?
What is this device in my ceiling that started chirping like a smoke detector last evening?
There is a button on it that says "test / silence". Unfortunately, there are several layers of floorboard in my attic so I can't figure out what it is wired to. I've actually installed a set of Nest Protect smoke detectors, so if it is a smoke detector or carbon monoxide detector I won't need it and it can be removed, but I would like to know what this is and how to remove.





Did the previous owner have monitoring by an outside monitoring service such as ADT?

"if it is a smoke detector or carbon monoxide detector I won't need it" would you really trust a Nest device with your life?

on amazon the model number for this device is P1010
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01A0M4EYU/

Yes I would trust nest as a smoke detector, they are interconnected so there is some redundancy and they automatically test themselves which is not something I've ever done with traditional first alerts or kidde. The path lighting is a major convenience feature IMO and can help prevent falls. @njzk2

It's a smoke detector made by First Alert. It's sold by Lowe's and others. It's hardwired, hence the wires. The chirping means that the backup battery is low.
You could remove it, but there's no harm in leaving it there and just replacing the backup battery. The problem with Nest and other products like that is that they become obsolete rather quick, depend on an active Internet connection, etc., while a regular smoke detector has one job and does that job well. In my own home, I have 4 Nest thermostats and have had to replace 3 of them in the last 3 years. I would not trust a Nest product with something as important as smoke detection.
Also, if the Nest smoke detector is battery-powered, your jurisdiction might not allow you to replace hardwired detectors with battery-powered. Check with your local fire chief.

Another issue with Nests and similar products is the software can have bugs which can cause very annoying issues. I think this has become rare, but the early "smart" detectors had occasional problems of going off for no reason and similar issues.

Nest smoke alarms don't need an active internet connection to detect and alarm.

Learned that this is from first alert but this one is not hard wired and was simply unscrewed. My nest next to it is hardwired and works great. I love the automated night lights on the nest, great safety feature. If you are in doubt these nest really rock!

In the UK smoke detectors (and heat detectors in kitchens) are required to be replaced after ten years and are sold with expiry dates.  The chirps from a depleted backup battery are the same.

Good point.  I may be mistaken, but my understanding is that requirement now extends to multiple jurisdictions (countries, states, regions, etc.) around our planet.

And some of those requirements include hard-wired detectors rather than independent battery-powered ones. Local codes will indicate whether a hard-wired detector can be removed or if it has to be replaced with something equivalent. (I, at least, don't know if the Nest Protect product OP mentions qualifies.)

To clarify, the radioactive source has a life of about 10 years regardless of how the unit is powered.   Modern units tend to have CR123 batteries as back-up to the hard wire link, these batteries are good for 5-7 years.

Nest has both battery-powered and hard-wired devices, which use the same wiring as other hard-wired devices.
